# Gram-js. Problem with message.sendMedia, channels.editPhoto

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I am creating a telegram client to create templates channels. I got mainly all the functionality I wanted but I got stuck with all the functionality that implies upload media:

- message.sendMedia (https://gram.js.org/tl/messages/SendMedia)
- channel.editPhoto (https://gram.js.org/tl/channels/EditPhoto)

When I use the message.sendMedia method I always get this error:

```
Error: Disconnect (caused from messages.SendMedia)
at /Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/Telegram-Bots/gram-js/node_modules/telegram/extensions/MessagePacker.js:107:33
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at MessagePacker.rejectAll (/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/Telegram-Bots/gram-js/node_modules/telegram/extensions/MessagePacker.js:105:29)
at MTProtoSender._disconnect (/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/Telegram-Bots/gram-js/node_modules/telegram/network/MTProtoSender.js:249:25)
at MTProtoSender.disconnect (/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/Telegram-Bots/gram-js/node_modules/telegram/network/MTProtoSender.js:168:20)
at TelegramClient.disconnect (/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/Telegram-Bots/gram-js/node_modules/telegram/client/telegramBaseClient.js:163:32)
at _updateLoop (/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/Telegram-Bots/gram-js/node_modules/telegram/client/updates.js:177:26)
```

And this one is the code I am executing:

```
const sendMedia = async (channelId) => {
    const file = await client.uploadFile({
        file: new CustomFile(
            'stakazo.jpeg',
            fs.statSync(
                '/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/Telegram-Bots/gram-js/images/xxxxx.jpeg'
            ).size,
            '/Users/apple/Desktop/Projects/Telegram-Bots/gram-js/images/xxxxxx.jpeg'
        ),
        workers: 1,
    });

    const result = await client.invoke(
        new Api.messages.SendMedia({
            peer: channelId,
            media: new Api.InputMediaUploadedPhoto({
                file: file,
                ttlSeconds: 43,
            }),
            message: 'Hello there!',
            randomId: BigInt('-4156887774564'),
            scheduleDate: 43,
        })
    );
};
```

I am really stuck here. I thought I might be a problem with the image but did not get to find out anything.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this code to send the file(image, doc etc.).

```js
await client.sendMessage("me", {
   message: "test send file", //leave it empty if don't want to send the message with the image
   file: fileName,
});
```

For more information refer to this article -> https://gram.js.org/beta/classes/TelegramClient.html#sendFile